# How do I disable the security certificate check in Python requests

Tags: python, https, python-requests

I am using

```
import requests
requests.post(url='https://foo.example', data={'bar':'baz'})
```

but I get a request.exceptions.SSLError.
The website has an expired certficate, but I am not sending sensitive data, so it doesn't matter to me.
I would imagine there is an argument like 'verifiy=False' that I could use, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 865, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification):

> `requests` can also ignore verifying the SSL certificate if you set
> `verify` to False.
>
> ```
> >>> requests.get('https://kennethreitz.com', verify=False)
> <Response [200]>
> ```

If you're using a third-party module and want to disable the checks, here's a context manager that monkey patches `requests` and changes it so that `verify=False` is the default and suppresses the warning.

```
import warnings
import contextlib

import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

old_merge_environment_settings = requests.Session.merge_environment_settings

@contextlib.contextmanager
def no_ssl_verification():
    opened_adapters = set()

    def merge_environment_settings(self, url, proxies, stream, verify, cert):
        # Verification happens only once per connection so we need to close
        # all the opened adapters once we're done. Otherwise, the effects of
        # verify=False persist beyond the end of this context manager.
        opened_adapters.add(self.get_adapter(url))

        settings = old_merge_environment_settings(self, url, proxies, stream, verify, cert)
        settings['verify'] = False

        return settings

    requests.Session.merge_environment_settings = merge_environment_settings

    try:
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter('ignore', InsecureRequestWarning)
            yield
    finally:
        requests.Session.merge_environment_settings = old_merge_environment_settings

        for adapter in opened_adapters:
            try:
                adapter.close()
            except:
                pass
```

Here's how you use it:

```
with no_ssl_verification():
    requests.get('https://wrong.host.badssl.example/')
    print('It works')

    requests.get('https://wrong.host.badssl.example/', verify=True)
    print('Even if you try to force it to')

requests.get('https://wrong.host.badssl.example/', verify=False)
print('It resets back')

session = requests.Session()
session.verify = True

with no_ssl_verification():
    session.get('https://wrong.host.badssl.example/', verify=True)
    print('Works even here')

try:
    requests.get('https://wrong.host.badssl.example/')
except requests.exceptions.SSLError:
    print('It breaks')

try:
    session.get('https://wrong.host.badssl.example/')
except requests.exceptions.SSLError:
    print('It breaks here again')
```

Note that this code closes all open adapters that handled a patched request once you leave the context manager. This is because requests maintains a per-session connection pool and certificate validation happens only once per connection so unexpected things like this will happen:

```
>>> import requests
>>> session = requests.Session()
>>> session.get('https://wrong.host.badssl.example/', verify=False)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:857: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
<Response [200]>
>>> session.get('https://wrong.host.badssl.example/', verify=True)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:857: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works if you have few requests calls inside your own code, but imagine that I want to disable this in a third partly library that uses requests,... it would be impossible to fix the 3rd party lib like this.

Comment: @sorin: Just monkey patch `requests` and have `verify` default to `False`.

Comment: How do I suppress the big nasty warning message that still gets printed?

Comment: @Michael to answer my own question: `requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()`

Comment: @Michael: or to avoid hiding all warnings: `from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning` then `requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(category=InsecureRequestWarning)`

Comment: `warnings.resetwarnings()` doesn't seem to re-enable the warning!

Comment: As written, this only works if the `requests.get` call does not explicitly set `verify=True`.  If you need that, you need to re-define `partialmethod` to find and strip out the right kwarg or remove the right index of position in `self.args`.

Comment: @JakeStevens-Haas: Good catch, thanks. I've updated the context manager.

Comment: For python > 2.16.0 need to use: import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

Comment: @PrashantShubham: It works fine for me in a fresh virtualenv. `urllib3.disable_warnings(category)` literally just calls `warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category)`.

Comment: Why is the library verifying the certificate when the scheme is explicitly HTTP in a url?

Comment: @Thomas: Do you have `allow_redirects=True` somewhere? What's the URL?

Comment: I am using it to access a local service that is in development, so it's http://bot and there is absolutely no SSL, etc

Comment: @Thomas: that shouldn't be happening and isn't really related to this question. If you include all the info in a separate question I'm sure somebody could help

Comment: I did and it was flagged as a duplicate of this one :) the solution is the same in the end, I'm just questioning why it checks the certificates if you explicitly give a http url

Comment: @Thomas: In that case, try using Wireshark or something to check exactly what's happening.

Comment: The problem itself is well documented, there are a lot of threads about issues with Python/SSL/macOS. But I realized that I don't care about SSL in my specific case, the issue is that requests automatically uses https, even if you specify http in the url. In that case, the problem is really an issue within requests because if http is specified, it shouldn't even try to go with ssl, but somehow it wants the url to be qualified with http or https and yet ignores what it is and goes with https; so I came here to find a workaround

Comment: @Thomas: I've never heard of or experienced requests ignoring your protocol and switching to HTTPS. I develop on macOS and use requests frequently. Could you make a self-contained example?

Comment: The issue showed up because ssl doesn’t work with python on my Mac; there are a lot of threads about the problem but since I don’t need ssl i didn’t spend much time on it. I am not sure what are the layers involved with establishing a connection in python but since it doesn’t just affect requests, the problem has to be somewhere else. It looks like no matter the protocol, a verification is done

Comment: Hi there, I have a request that gives me the response of post request in the Postman by disabling the 'SSL certificate verification' in the setting option. But, if I get the python request code that provided by the Postman, I will receive the "SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed" error and adding the 'verify=False' does not help in this case, Is there any solution to get the response of the Postman in the python request script?

Comment: @Blender, What happened security point of you, If we setup 'verify=False` with getting warning `Unverified HTTP request..` ? another, If I set `verify=True` then request not work , getting error like `request.exception.SSError..Max retries exceeded with url:` ? which one best solution.

Answer (score 198):

Use `requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()` and `verify=False` on `requests` methods.

```py
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

# Suppress only the single warning from urllib3 needed.
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(category=InsecureRequestWarning)

# Set `verify=False` on `requests.post`.
requests.post(url='https://example.com', data={'bar':'baz'}, verify=False)
```

Comment: Your answer is usefull when you want to get rid of Warnings like "Unverified HTTPS request is being made".
     
But ``verify=False`` must to be present anyway. Tnx.

Comment: And to avoid hiding all warnings: `from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning` then `requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(category=InsecureRequestWarning)`

Comment: For those who can't disable warnings, you can try `requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)`. This works because it ensures the `urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning` is the exact one used by `requests`.

Comment: What happened security point of you, If we setup 'verify=False` with getting warning `Unverified HTTP request..` ? another, If I set `verify=True` then request not work , getting error like `request.exception.SSError..Max retries exceeded with url:` ? which one best solution.

Comment: Would I want to reset this after the requests call so that these warnings show up again? How would I re-enable the warnings?

Answer (score 75):

To add to [Blender's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15445989/3357935), you can disable SSL certificate validation for all requests using `Session.verify = False`

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False
session.post(url='https://example.com', data={'bar':'baz'})
```

Note that `urllib3`, (which Requests uses), [strongly discourages](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings) making unverified HTTPS requests and will raise an `InsecureRequestWarning`.

Comment: still I need to set this `session.trust_env = False` to make it work due to `**CA_BUNDLE` variable.

Answer (score 42):

Also can be done with a environment variable:

```
export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=""
```

Comment: This gives me: "OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: "" . I'm using request 2.22.0

Comment: or `export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE='your-ca.pem'`

Comment: This seems to be the best answer in case you need to use a library that you cannot edit

Comment: Based on [CURL_CA_BUNDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445981/how-do-i-disable-the-security-certificate-check-in-python-requests#comment104417247_58955034), `os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = 'FiddlerRootCertificate_Base64_Encoded_X.509.cer.pem'  # your-ca.pem` works for Python 3.8.3 when using [google-cloud-bigquery 1.24.0](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/) and [BigQuery Client Lib for Python](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#install_the_client_library)

Comment: `export CURL_CA_BUNDLE="" ` seems to no longer work after 2.28.0. From https://pyup.io/packages/pypi/requests/changelog

---
Fixed bug where setting `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` to an empty string would disable cert verification. All Requests 2.x versions before 2.28.0 are affected. (6074)

Answer (score 18):

If you are writing a scraper and really don't care about the SSL certificate you can set it global:

```
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

**DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION**

edit, comment from @Misty

> Not working. Requests now uses **urllib3**, which create its own
> SSLContext. You can override cert_reqs instead

```
ssl.SSLContext.verify_mode = property(lambda self: ssl.CERT_NONE, lambda self, newval: None)
```

Comment: Not working. Requests now uses urllib3, which create its own SSLContext. You can override cert_reqs instead ```ssl.SSLContext.verify_mode = property(lambda self: ssl.CERT_NONE, lambda self, newval: None)```

Comment: @Misty Good addition thanks! indeed answer is for previous versions (2021)

Answer (score 13):

If you want to send exactly post request with verify=False option, fastest way is to use this code:

```
import requests

requests.api.request('post', url, data={'bar':'baz'}, json=None, verify=False)
```

Comment: Bandit won't be happy when you disable verify=False. See: https://docs.openstack.org/bandit/latest/plugins/b501_request_with_no_cert_validation.html

Comment: Hi there, I have a request that gives me the response of post request in the Postman by disabling the 'SSL certificate verification' in the setting option. But, if I get the python request code that provided by the Postman, I will receive the "SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed" error and adding the 'verify=False' does not help in this case, Is there any solution to get the response of the Postman in the python request script?

Answer (score 13):

### What has worked for me Due [`verify=False` Bug](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/3829)

Due to a bug on [`session.verify=False`](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/3829) that makes `urllib*` ignore
that when a environment variable (`CURL_CA_BUNDLE`) is set. So we set it to nothing.

```
import requests, os
session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False
session.trust_env = False
os.environ['CURL_CA_BUNDLE']="" # or whaever other is interfering with 
session.post(url='https://example.com', data={'bar':'baz'})
```

Not sure I need `trust_env`

Answer (score 5):

You can disable ssl verification globally and also disable the warnings using the below approach in the entry file of your code

```
import requests

# disable ssl warning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

# override the methods which you use
requests.post = lambda url, **kwargs: requests.request(
    method="POST", url=url, verify=False, **kwargs
)

requests.get = lambda url, **kwargs: requests.request(
    method="GET", url=url, verify=False, **kwargs
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Bit late to the party.

In python 3.8 and requests (2.28.2) it is possible to disable those warnings on urllib3(https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings) via requests i.e.

```
import requests
requests.urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

Answer (score 2):

python 3.6+

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="Unverified HTTPS request")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you work with [websockets](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/) package then [ssl](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) package provides `ssl._create_unverified_context()` method, that disables certificates verification. I had to use it for my websocket app that uses self singed ssl certificates.

#### Example

```py
import ssl


ctx = ssl._create_unverified_context()
url = f"wss://localhost:8001/ws/v1/alert"

async with websockets.connect(url, ssl=ctx) as websocket:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

first import ssl then make a variable like this with three lines of code in your python script file-

```
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
```

An Example that I have use in html parsing with beautifulsoup was like this -

```
import urllib.request,urllib.parse,urllib.error

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE


url = input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable SSL verification globally (not a good idea, but it has its uses), as [Authlib states](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/requests.html#self-signed-certificate):

> You can force all requests to disable SSL verification by setting your environment variable `CURL_CA_BUNDLE=""`.

However, `requests` uses the enviroment variable `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` in order to list all CAs, but you can force it to "fall back" on `CURL_CA_BUNDLE`.

In their [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/?highlight=REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE#ssl-cert-verification):

> This list of trusted CAs can also be specified through the `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable. If `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` is not set, `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` will be used as fallback.

So, you can just change the enviroment variables at the begining of your script:

```py
import os

os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = ""
os.environ['CURL_CA_BUNDLE'] = ""  # in most instances you don't even need this
```