# Bypassing Certificate Verification in Python 2.6

Tags: python, ssl

Is there a way I can bypass certificate verification in Python 2.6.
I get the SSL:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error when I try to download the file. I am using the urllib2 library to open the url to download a file. I am unable to use contexts because it is not supported in python 2.6.

Comment: Can you switch to the `requests` library? http://stackoverflow.com/q/15445981/1394393 (`requests` is generally a better library for most usage overall anyway.)