# Web crawler error

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I'm completely new to Python. I'm starting an internship in January and they want me getting up to speed in Python as much as possible prior to starting. 
So I made this web crawler just for practice, and I'm pretty sure my code is OK. I have the code below, I could post the errors it incurs, but it's literally pages worth of errors all from the requests package. Can I fix this? Is it my code or is there something deeper going on?

(I'm having trouble formatting the code in this window, but it is all formatted correctly in my actual editor, there are no syntax errors)

**Code**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://www.thenewboston.com/forum/recent_activity.php?page=' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'title'}):
            href = link.get('href')
            print(href)
        page += 1

trade_spider(3)
```

**Errors**

All of the errors are from this file: 
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py

A bunch of small errors within that file

Also this error

requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)

**Possible Conclusion**

Since none of the errors are within my code and they're all in the requests package, I'm guessing that package is broken or something, or there is something outdated about my software or the requests package?

Any help is appreciated. I'm just trying to learn some Python and I would be so happy if I could create a functioning web crawler.

Comment: Let me get this straight. You're completely new to Python, this is your first ever program, and you assume that it's *requests*, one of the most popular of all Python libraries, that is broken?

Comment: You might be looking for the `title text-semibold` class attribute instead of `title`. Each video has the former on its link.

Comment: @DanielRoseman He means that his installation might have had errors or something.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445981/how-do-i-disable-the-security-certificate-check-in-python-requests. Accepted answer has the solution (use verify=False with requests.get(...))

Answer (score 0):

Use `source_code = requests.get(url, verify=False)` to disable SSL checking.