# POST request with oauth bearer key in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth

I am just one and half week old in python, so please bear my ignorance-

I am trying to make a POST call with oauth key-

the code I am using-

```
import requests
import json


url = "https://monkeyman.com/private/bananaintelligence/merchant"

datas = {
   "merchantLookup" : [
       {
          "name": "BananaPi",
          "postcode": "10011",
          "country": "USA"
       }

    ]
}

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization':'Bearer hiuqbqjbdyqgf6etyqgeqk!$#$DFWEDWEFWEFERGREGERGRHG$%#T#T#T#T##TERGEGEGEGEGE'}

rsp = requests.post(url, json=datas, headers=headers)
```

Error -

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)
```

I know that key is fine since it's working fine with my spring boot app and also from postman, is there any specific way in python to pass Authorization key.  Help!

Answer (score 0):

The ssl certificate failed to be verified. You can just skip ssl verification with `verify=False`.

`rsp = requests.post(url, json=datas, headers=headers, verify=False)`

Comment: API I am calling has oauth validation. it's a third party API I pretty sure skipping authorization will not get me desired response.

Comment: is this helps ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445981/how-do-i-disable-the-security-certificate-check-in-python-requests (i'm not sure..)

Comment: tried, didn't help -InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://securitybot/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)

Comment: but this test made sure that code is ok and trying to make ssl handshakes. thanks

Comment: is there any specific way in python to pass Authorization key