# How to suppress warnings about lack of cert verification in a requests HTTPS call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, python-requests, suppress-warnings

I would like to disable the warning about a lack of certificate verification in a HTTPS call using `requests`.

The question has been asked in the past, leading to answers about [disabling a relevant request logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32282390/903011) or the [`urllib3` SSL warning](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings).

This used to work in the past (I remember successfully silencing the warnings) but seems not to work anymore?

I put together the two solutions which worked so far:

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170124] on linux
>>> import requests
>>> import requests.packages
>>> import urllib3
>>> urllib3.disable_warnings()
>>> requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
>>> requests.get('https://www.google.com', verify=False)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:845: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
<Response [200]>
```

**Is there another (current) solution to silence these warnings?**

Comment: Can you verify that `import urllib3`, then `urllib3.__file__` produces `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py`?

Comment: The `.disable_warnings()` call only runs `warnings.simplefilter('ignore', urllib3.exceptions.HTTPWarning)` (and `InsecureRequestWarning` is an indirect subclass of `HTTPWarning`, so is also ignored).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes, `urllib3.__file__` produces `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py`

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue then. Can you show that `import warnings; [(w[0], w[2]) for w in warnings.filters]` consists of?

Comment: (note that `requests.packages.urllib3` is just an alias for `urllib3` now; you can see this when you echo `requests.packages.urllib3.__file__` in your interpreter, it'll produce `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py`)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```

There are two different ways to do this, both of these work.
You will have to add this to your imports

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
```

Comment: You can just do it all in one line, without the additional `import`: ```requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)```

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using
**requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()**

Use
**requests.urllib3.disable_warnings()**

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).