# How can I modify python warnings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, warnings

I have a requirement where I need to modify a python warning i.e I need to print a "user-friendly" warning message If I get a warning from the code. I don't want the file name on stdout.

```
with requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=300,verify='/etc/ssl/certs/') as r:
```

I get a warning which prints the file name if the URL is self-signed.

Comment: Read this [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to suppress warnings about lack of cert verification in a requests HTTPS call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767143/how-to-suppress-warnings-about-lack-of-cert-verification-in-a-requests-https-cal)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer No, It's not duplicate. There is a difference between "suppress" and "modify"

Comment: @shaikmoeed Thanks, I got the solution, we can get the warning in a warning object and we can do whatever with that after.

Comment: @Ashwani you may want to add an answer illustrating the solution...

Comment: @DanCornilescu Thanks, I have added the solution I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    with requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=300, verify='/etc/ssl/certs/') as r:
       if w: 
          print w[0].message
```

If there is any warning returned by request.get() then that warning will be available in w[0].message variable and If you want to modify it, you can.