# How to bypass 'SLError: HTTPSConnectionPool' behind corporate firewall in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I'm attempting to access the FINRA ATS API using Python (3.7.1) and the Requests package behind a corporate firewall, but I keep receiving the `'SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool'` error listed below. I have also tried Solution #1 and `'os.environ["PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY"] = "0"` to no avail, but I was able to execute a CURL script and successfully pull data from the API after adding `-k --insecure` inputs. Does anyone know of a way to completely ignore/disable verifying the SSL certificate or another workaround?

## Code

```
import requests

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json',}

data = '{ "compareFilters": [ { "compareType": "EQUAL", "fieldName": "lastUpdateDate","fieldValue": "2019-01-22" },{ \"compareType\": \"EQUAL\", \"fieldName\": \"tierDescription\",\"fieldValue\": \"NMS Tier 1\" }] ,"limit":99999999 }'

response = requests.post('https://api.finra.org/data/group/otcMarket/name/weeklySummary', headers=headers, data=data)

data = response.json()
```

## SSLError

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.finra.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /data/group/otcMarket/name/weeklySummary (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl_choose_client_version', 'inappropriate fallback')])")))
```

## Solution #1 (Attempted and Failed)

[How do I disable the security certificate check in Python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445981/how-do-i-disable-the-security-certificate-check-in-python-requests)