# in Python, I want to do rest requests with HTTP and NOT with HTTPS, packages don't seem to agree

Tags: python, python-requests, httplib2

I have tried to use request:

```
url = 'http://bot'    # this is a local service
import requests

r = requests.get(url)
```

and I get

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bot', port=443)

I specified HTTP, not HTTPS, but it tried to connect with SSL.

So, I tried httplib2:

```
url = 'http://bot'    # this is a local service
response, content = http.request(url, "GET")
```

and I get:

> ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)

I don't know why there is an obsession with HTTPS, but I don't want it. it's a local service running in development and it is pure HTTP. Adding ":80" to the url doesn't change anything.

When using CURL or C# to access the same service, through HTTP, no problem.

How can I tell python libs that I want a pure HTTP connection and nothing else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable the security certificate check in Python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445981/how-do-i-disable-the-security-certificate-check-in-python-requests)

Comment: @Piotr, agreed; it's a duplicate

Comment: It's a duplicate but when people don't know what a security certificate check is, they'll probably find this one, which will point to the right direction either way.

Comment: Roman has a point: I searched for a solution and since I didn't use the right terms, I couldn't find any; keeping this one open might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `requests` library and add a ssl verify option. Your request line should look like this:

```
r = requests.get(url, verify = False)
```

Comment: It works! I don't understand why it tries to verify a HTTP scheme though

Comment: @Thomas this is because your 'bot' has no SSL setup, and by default, `requests` always verifies SSL, so you need to tell it NO (verify = False)

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable SSL_VERIFICATION

```
r = requests.get(url, verify = False)
```