# Python Requests SSL error: hostname doesn't mactch either of

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, python-requests

I'm trying to connect to one of my internal services at: https://myservice.my-alternative-domain.com through Python Requests. I'm using Python 3.6

I'm using a custom CA bundle to verify the request, and I'm getting the next error:

SSLError: hostname 'myservice.my-domain.com' doesn't match either of 'my-domain.com', 'my-alternative-domain.com'

The SSL certificate that the internal service uses has as CN: my-domain.com, and as SAN (Subject Alternative Names): 'my-domain.com', 'my-alternative-domain.com'

So, I'm trying to access the service through one of the alternative names (this has to be like this and it's not under my control)

I think the error is correct, and that the certificate should have also as SAN:

'*.my-alternative-domain.com'

in order for the request to work.

The only thing that puzzles me is that I can access the service through the browser.

Can somebody confirm the behavior of Python Requests is correct?

This is how I call the service:

```
response = requests.get('https://myservice.my-alternative-domain.com', params=params, headers=headers, verify=ca_bundle)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting SSL verify to false?
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445981/how-do-i-disable-the-security-certificate-check-in-python-requests for more details

Comment: If I set SSL verfiy to false, it works. But I want the verification to work with my custom CA bundle. It's a requirement for me.

Comment: I think you need to provide both more details about your certificate (CN, SAN) and your code.

Comment: The CN is: 'my-domain.com'. the SAN are: 'my-alternative-domain.com' and 'my-domain.com. I'll update the question with this and the code

Comment: The way you describe it the behavior of requests is correct. Are you sure that the browser gets exactly the same certificate and visits exactly the same site?

Comment: Yes @Steffen, it seems so. And that's what really intrigues me. The service is deployed using Kubernetes, if that information is any relevant

Answer (score -3, accepted):

pass verify as false might work

> x=requests.get(-----,verify=false)

Comment: I want to verify the request with my CA Bundle, that's the whole point

Comment: NEVER disable certificate verification. You nullify almost all usefulness of TLS then, and you might as well revert back to plain text.