# Accessing REST API in Apache Ignite Using HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, ignite, rest

> I am using Apache Ignite 2.8.0.
>   This is my server configuration,

```
<property name="sslContextFactory">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.ssl.SslContextFactory">
        <property name="keyStoreFilePath" value="C:\\ignite\\apache-ignite-2.8.0-bin\\keystore.jks"/>
        <property name="keyStorePassword" value="1234567"/>
        <property name="trustStoreFilePath" value="C:\\ignite\\\\apache-ignite-2.8.0-bin\\\\trust.jks"/>
        <property name="trustStorePassword" value="123456"/>
    </bean>
</property> 
<property name="connectorConfiguration">

              <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.ConnectorConfiguration">

                    <property name="jettyPath" value="C:\apache-ignite-2.8.0-bin\examples\config\jetty-config.xml" />

              </bean>

        </property>
```

> And This is My jetty-config.xml,
>           https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api (Copy pasted)
>
> Still it works with HTTP only.. It doesn't work with HTTPS. What is wrong with me?
>   How I can enable the HTTPS on Rest API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [documentation snippet](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api#sample-jetty-xml-configuration) is not complete.

You also need sslContextFactory defined **in jetty configuration**:

```
<New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
    <Set name="keyStorePath">src/test/keystore/server.jks</Set>
    <Set name="keyStorePassword">123456</Set>
    <Set name="keyManagerPassword">123456</Set>
    <Set name="trustStorePath">src/test/keystore/trust-one.jks</Set>
    <Set name="trustStorePassword">123456</Set>
</New>
```

You also need a differently configured connector:

```
<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
            <Arg><Ref refid="Server"/></Arg>
            <Arg>
                <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
                    <Item>
                        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory">
                            <Arg><Ref refid="sslContextFactory"/></Arg>
                            <Arg>http/1.1</Arg>
                        </New>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                            <Arg><Ref refid="httpCfg"/></Arg>
                        </New>
                    </Item>
                </Array>
            </Arg>
  ...
```

You also need trust store and signed server key. Generating those, especially ones which may be accepted by web browsers, is way out of scope of this answer. Try letsencrypt for generating these, perhaps.

Comment: Yes It works with HTTPS.. but i get your connection to this site is Not Secure in my browser. what can i do?

Comment: "Generating certificates which may be accepted by web browsers is way out of scope of this answer. Try letsencrypt for generating these, perhaps."

Comment: Actually i am using python for give https request.  import requests
URL = "https://127.0.0.1:8080//ignite?cmd=version"
r = requests.get(url = URL ) 
print(r).......... This gives SSL Error for me

Comment: Try adding verify=False https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445981/how-do-i-disable-the-security-certificate-check-in-python-requests

Comment: Maybe it's because you have double slash? Anyway, getting 404 shows you're on the right track

Comment: Actually i need to get my version of ignite for that request. but it gives 404, then how did you say it's right?

Comment: Try removing extra slash: 127.0.0.1:8080/ignite?cmd=version