# Why does my discord bot raise this error?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am developing a basic discord bot for fun and I am getting errors.

I have this basic Discord bot:

```
import discord
from tweet import tweet

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is ready!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("j!tweet"):
        user = message.author.display_name
        tweetToTweet = message.content
        tweetToTweet = tweetToTweet.replace('j!tweet', '')
        tweet(user, tweetToTweet)
        await message.channel.send("Tweeted!")

client.run(MYTOKEN)
```

It is raising this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 936, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 981, in create_connection
    ssl_handshake_timeout=ssl_handshake_timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1009, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 530, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 774, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/usr/PycharmProjects/discordBot/app.py", line 22, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 261, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 165, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 483, in _request
    timeout=real_timeout
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 859, in _create_connection
    req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 986, in _create_direct_connection
    req=req, client_error=client_error)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 939, in _wrap_create_connection
    req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')]
```

What does this error mean? Why is this occurring? I have no idea at this moment what the error is, so it would be great if I could figure out the issue.

Comment: Looks like the certificate validation fails, most probably because your local trust store does not posses necessary root CA certificates. You can either fix it (which is the correct approach, but often hard to do), or disable it (example like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445981/how-do-i-disable-the-security-certificate-check-in-python-requests).

Comment: @MarekPuchalski how can i fix it? I am on macos, and I did try doing one of the solutions online, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, discord doesn't allow you to connect (this is what I understand from the image). I suggest to do this instead of the first 4 lines:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import tweet
client = command.Bot(commands_prefix='YOUR_PREFIX')
```

Comment: Why does this solve a `SSLCertVerificationError`?

Comment: I don't really know, maybe you are just testing from your local machine and that's the problem but I don't know. I issued this problem time ago with discord.Client() and I solved it with the method I told you.