# SSLError with Python requests after certificate upgrade

Tags: python-requests, ssl-certificate, runtime-error

I just updated certificates on my server.

After that I am getting this error:

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.164.1.1', port=9999): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/nice_endpoint (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))

Answer (score 1):

Try this first:

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

If it does help, try this

```
sudo pip uninstall -y certifi
sudo pip install certifi== xx.xx.xx # e.g., 2015.04.28
```

Answer (score 0):

May be insecure, but you could [ignore SSL certificate verification with requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/?highlight=ignore+verifying#ssl-cert-verification) by passing `verify=False` like:

```py
requests.get('your_url_here', verify=False)
```

See: [How do I disable the security certificate check in Python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445981/how-do-i-disable-the-security-certificate-check-in-python-requests)