# Getting Error: requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, openssl, ssl-certificate

I use module requests (I use python 3.12) to get url:
[text](https://portal.vietcombank.com.vn/Usercontrols/TVPortal.TyGia/pXML.aspx).
This is my simple code:

```
import requests

URL = "https://portal.vietcombank.com.vn/Usercontrols/TVPortal.TyGia/pXML.aspx"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/118.0.2088.46"
}

res = requests.get(URL, timeout=10, headers=headers)
print(res)
```

My chrome accesses this web normally.

---

This is my error that I got:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='portal.vietcombank.com.vn', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /Usercontrols/TVPortal.TyGia/pXML.aspx (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)')))
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='portal.vietcombank.com.vn', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /Usercontrols/TVPortal.TyGia/pXML.aspx (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "D:\project_data\test1.py", line 16, in <module>
    res = requests.get(URL, timeout=10, headers=headers)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='portal.vietcombank.com.vn', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /Usercontrols/TVPortal.TyGia/pXML.aspx (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)')))
```

Comment: I think it's connected problem with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66405553/sslerror-with-python-requests-after-certificate-upgrade?rq=2

Comment: `unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)')))` - this is due to Open SSL 3, have a look at this question for possible solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71603314/7750891

Comment: You can use javascript fetch instead of python requests if you want a quick fix. [here](https://pastebin.com/z6DfJCMQ) is the code i've written for your needs. Make sure to do`npm install fetch` in your script's directory before running

Comment: I tried the above options when searching with google but they didn't work. It's annoying that Chrome can read requests but python requests can't?