# Error when trying to downloads resources in python

Tags: python, download

everyone,

I was trying to run this code:

```
download_utils.download_all_keras_resources("readonly/keras/models",
    "readonly/keras/datasets")
```

But I am receiving this error:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /hse-aml/intro-to-dl/releases/download/v0.2/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

I am starting with python so I have no idea of what may be the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: The ssl handshake is not processed correctly. If you want you can skip the verification using [verify=False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445981/how-do-i-disable-the-security-certificate-check-in-python-requests).

Comment: Your program is calling the requests module in python. I cant say from where but it has a provision to disable ssl authentication.

Comment: hey, @AlbinPaul, Idk if thats what you meant, but I tried `git config --global http.sslVerify False` on Git Bash and conda config `--set ssl_verify False` on Anaconda Prompt and then tried to run the code again but the error didnt disappear