# Python requests: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate

Tags: python, nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I trying to terminate SSL on NGINX by passing the upstream server as a proxy.
The working environment is on localhost.

I have tried by all means to suppress the error, but it won't

**NGINX Config**

```
stream {
    upstream stream_backend {
         server localhost:5011;
         
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        proxy_pass            stream_backend;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/proxypool.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/proxypool.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_session_timeout 4h;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    }
}
```

**The way I'm generating the certificate**

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 9999 -newkey rsa:2048 \
    -keyout /etc/ssl/private/proxypool.key \
    -out /etc/ssl/certs/proxypool.crt
```

*With empty answer to all prompts

**The way I'm performing the request**

```
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://localhost',
    'https': 'https://localhost'
}

response = requests.post(
    'https://api.ipify.org?format=json',
    proxies=proxies,
    verify="/etc/ssl/certs/proxypool.pem"
)
```

**The error**

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ipify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?format=json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)')))
```

**Things I tried with no success**

- Passing `verify=False`. Results in `certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'localhost'`
- Using a [SSL verification bypass context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445981/how-do-i-disable-the-security-certificate-check-in-python-requests)

Answer (score 1):

Add your self signed certificates to Python certs bundle, check where it is located by:

```
>>> import certifi
>>> certifi.where()
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/certifi/cacert.pem'
```

and add your certificates to the end of that file.