# Why can't upload file into the dropbox with proxy?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, proxy, dropbox

The `urllib` library installed in my os:

```
pip list |grep urllib
urllib3             1.25.11
```

I want to upload local file into the dropbox with proxy:

```
import dropbox
access_token = "xxxxxx"

file_from = "local_file"
file_to = "/directory_in_dropbox"

proxyDict = {
        "http": "http://127.0.0.1:8123",
        "https": "https://127.0.0.1:8123"
}

mysesh = dropbox.create_session(1,proxyDict)
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(access_token,session=mysesh)
with open(file_from, 'rb') as f:
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(), file_to)
```

It encounter errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dropbox/base.py", line 3208, in files_upload
    r = self.request(
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox_client.py", line 326, in request
    res = self.request_json_string_with_retry(host,
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox_client.py", line 476, in request_json_string_with_retry
    return self.request_json_string(host,
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox_client.py", line 589, in request_json_string
    r = self._session.post(url,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 590, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 966, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 500, in _connect_tls_proxy
    return ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 453, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 495, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 997, in _create
    raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

It's no use to write the proxy dict as below:

```
proxyDict = {
        "http": "http://127.0.0.1:8123",
        "https": "http://127.0.0.1:8123"
}
```

The proxy 127.0.0.1:8123 works fine,i can down resources from web with proxy in youtube-dl command:

```
youtube-dl --proxy http://127.0.0.1:8118 $url
```

Updated for Paulo's advice:

[image]
[image]

Updaed for Markus' advice:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
ssl.SSLContext.verify_mode = property(lambda self: ssl.CERT_NONE, lambda self, newval: None)

import dropbox
access_token = "xxxxxxxx"

file_from = "/home/debian/sample.sql"
file_to = "/mydoc"

proxyDict = {
        "http": "http://127.0.0.1:8123",
        "https": "https://127.0.0.1:8123"
}

mysesh = dropbox.create_session(1,proxyDict)
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(access_token,session=mysesh)
with open(file_from, 'rb') as f:
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(), file_to)
```

It encounter the below error:

```
/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:981: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host '127.0.0.1'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dropbox/base.py", line 3208, in files_upload
    r = self.request(
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox_client.py", line 326, in request
    res = self.request_json_string_with_retry(host,
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox_client.py", line 476, in request_json_string_with_retry
    return self.request_json_string(host,
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox_client.py", line 596, in request_json_string
    self.raise_dropbox_error_for_resp(r)
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox_client.py", line 639, in raise_dropbox_error_for_resp
    raise AuthError(request_id, err)
dropbox.exceptions.AuthError: AuthError('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', AuthError('invalid_access_token', None))
```

Update for   `Life is complex`'s advice:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your proxy at `127.0.0.1:8123` fully supports HTTP**S** (has certificate)? Try `"https": "http://127.0.0.1:8123",`

Comment: What happens if you bypass the ssl-checking? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15445989/18667225

Comment: Now it seems that the https connection succeeds, but the authentication fails. Have you double checked that the authentication works without proxy?

Comment: I am sure the token is correct ,please try the code with your token and dropbox account to see what happens.

Comment: Which proxy do you use?

Comment: It is kcptun to bypass gfw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried many times to get `mysesh = dropbox.create_session(1,proxyDict)` to work correctly.

I decided to look at the code for `dropbox-sdk-python` and noted that it is calling `requests.Session()`. So I decided to use that over `dropbox.create_session()`

```
import requests
from dropbox import Dropbox
from dropbox.files import WriteMode

access_token = "my_access_token"

file_from = 'test.docx'
file_to = '/test.docx'

# https://free-proxy-list.net
proxyDict = {
        "http": "http://50.218.57.65:80",
        "https": "https://83.229.73.175:80"
}
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = proxyDict

dbx = Dropbox(access_token, session=s)
with open(file_from, 'rb') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
    dbx.files_upload(f=file_content, path=file_to, mode=WriteMode.overwrite, mute=False)
```

Here is a screenshot of the file being written to DropBox.

[image]

I have tried this code with multiple proxy servers and it works each time.

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

So far, my understanding is it may be

- Miss-use of the urllib
- Bad https certificates

## Solution (maybe)

### urllib format

If I remember well urllib changed his format at some point from

```py
proxyDict = {
    'http':'8.88.888.8:8888',
    'https':'8.88.888.8:8888'
}
```

```py
proxyDict = {
    'https': 'https://8.88.888.8:8888',
    'http': 'http://8.88.888.8:8888',
}
```

Have you tried both format ?

Answer (score 0):

You must have a problem with

- your proxy not forwarding some stuff the right way or
- your access token is wrong
- the Dropbox app has the wrong permissions set

because this code (which is basically what you have in your question - even without disabling SSL certificate check!) works just fine with my access token put into the environment variable DROPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN.

```
import dropbox
import sys
import os

DROPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN = os.getenv('DROPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN')

def uploadFile(fromFilePath,toFilePath):
    proxy = '127.0.0.1:3128' # locally installed squid proxy server
    proxyDict = {
            "http": "http://"+proxy,
            "https": "http://"+proxy # connection to proxy is http!!
    }
    session = dropbox.create_session(1,proxyDict)
    client = dropbox.Dropbox(DROPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN,session)
    client.files_upload(open(fromFilePath, "rb").read(), toFilePath)
    print("Done uploading {} to {}".format(fromFilePath,toFilePath))

if __name__=="__main__":
    uploadFile(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
```

Be aware though, that the access token - once it is generated - has the permissions that were in effect at the time of token generation. If you change the app's permissions AFTER generating the token, the token will still have the original permissions!

**EDIT:** It looks like, the Dropbox API is clever enough to NOT use the proxy, if it can reach the target directly. Thus this code is working with ANYTHING you put into the proxyDict and it is not at all clear, if the code works, if it really has to go through the proxy. I am working on verifying that and will update the answer accordingly.

**Update:** I installed squid on my MacBook and used http://127.0.0.1:3128 as the proxy in above code, but the logs showed, the code never even tried to go through the proxy. But once I set the environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy to "http://127.0.0.1:3128" the request WOULD go through the proxy and proceed successfully. So... either there is something going on, I don't fully understand or the Dropbox API has some problem with the proxy definitions in the create_session call. Time to look at the API source code I guess...

Comment: Can't work in my pc.

Comment: @showkey You do realise, that in your question you are using different ports in the proxyDict and in your youtube-dl command, right? What kind of proxy are you running under 127.0.0.1:8123 (or 127.0.0.1:8118 for that matter)?

Answer (score 0):

Thank for `Life is complex`'s code,i add permission on Files and folders.

[image]

And re-generate the dropbox token ,execute the same code (nothing changed) with the new token ,done!
It is nothing related with proxy setting,just dropbox setting!

Comment: That is, what I told you to check already yesterday! ;-)