# SSL errors when sending file from Azure databricks to SharePoint

Tags: python, ssl, sharepoint, azure-databricks

We are working in a Python notebook on Databricks and want to send a file to a SharePoint site.

To achieve this, we obtained a `client_id` and `client_secret` from
`https://<SP_domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<my_site_name>/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx`

Locally, I can successfully send a file to SharePoint using these secrets. On DataBricks, I receive SSL Errors.

Normally, something like `verify=false` [within the `request`](https://jcutrer.com/python/requests-ignore-invalid-ssl-certificates) can be provided, ignoring SSL certificate checks (if that is the actual issue). But this does not seem to be supported in the Python package that I am using: `Office365-REST-Python-Client`

### The message of the errors that are received without any attempt to circumvent the issue.

`SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<SP_domain>.sharepoint.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sites/<my sites name>(Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1129)')))`

### Reproducible code

```
sharepoint_url = 'https://....sharepoint.com/sites/...'

client_credentials = ClientCredential(client_id=, client_secret=)

ctx = ClientContext(sharepoint_url).with_credentials(client_credentials)

web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()             # <<< Crashes here
print(web.properties["Url"])
```

Results in:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Actual (not the last) error states:

`MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nsdigitaal.sharepoint.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sites/Team-Camerainspectie (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1129)')))`

Full stack (sorry in advance :P)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLEOFError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    698             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 699             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    700                 conn,

/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    381         try:
--> 382             self._validate_conn(conn)
    383         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
   1009         if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
-> 1010             conn.connect()
   1011 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in connect(self)
    415 
--> 416         self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
    417             sock=conn,

/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir, key_password, ca_cert_data, tls_in_tls)
    448     if send_sni:
--> 449         ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
    450             sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname=server_hostname

/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, ssl_context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
    492     if server_hostname:
--> 493         return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
    494     else:

/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    499         # ctx._wrap_socket()
--> 500         return self.sslsocket_class._create(
    501             sock=sock,

/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py in _create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
   1039                         raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
-> 1040                     self.do_handshake()
   1041             except (OSError, ValueError):

/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py in do_handshake(self, block)
   1308                 self.settimeout(None)
-> 1309             self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1310         finally:

SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1129)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    438             if not chunked:
--> 439                 resp = conn.urlopen(
    440                     method=request.method,

/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    754 
--> 755             retries = retries.increment(
    756                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]

/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    573         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 574             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    575 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<tenant name>.sharepoint.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sites/<site name> (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1129)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-e6edc2d5-a811-4e43-a0ea-d29958d03122/lib/python3.9/site-packages/office365/runtime/auth/providers/acs_token_provider.py in get_app_only_access_token(self)
     40         try:
---> 41             realm = self._get_realm_from_target_url()
     42             url_info = urlparse(self.url)

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-e6edc2d5-a811-4e43-a0ea-d29958d03122/lib/python3.9/site-packages/office365/runtime/auth/providers/acs_token_provider.py in _get_realm_from_target_url(self)
     69     def _get_realm_from_target_url(self):
---> 70         response = requests.head(url=self.url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer'})
     71         return self.process_realm_response(response)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py in head(url, **kwargs)
    101     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', False)
--> 102     return request('head', url, **kwargs)
    103 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     60     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 61         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     62 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    541         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 542         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    543 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    654         # Send the request
--> 655         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    656 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    513                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
--> 514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<tenant name>.sharepoint.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sites/<site name> (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1129)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-4083654498839573> in <cell line: 14>()
     12 web = ctx.web
     13 ctx.load(web)
---> 14 ctx.execute_query()
     15 print(web.properties["Url"])

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-e6edc2d5-a811-4e43-a0ea-d29958d03122/lib/python3.9/site-packages/office365/runtime/client_runtime_context.py in execute_query(self)
    145     def execute_query(self):
    146         """Submit request(s) to the server"""
--> 147         self.pending_request().execute_query()
    148 
    149     def add_query(self, query):

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-e6edc2d5-a811-4e43-a0ea-d29958d03122/lib/python3.9/site-packages/office365/runtime/client_request.py in execute_query(self)
     72                 request = self.build_request(qry)
     73                 self.beforeExecute.notify(request)
---> 74                 response = self.execute_request_direct(request)
     75                 response.raise_for_status()
     76                 self.process_response(response)

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-e6edc2d5-a811-4e43-a0ea-d29958d03122/lib/python3.9/site-packages/office365/runtime/odata/request.py in execute_request_direct(self, request)
     34         """
     35         self._build_specific_request(request)
---> 36         return super(ODataRequest, self).execute_request_direct(request)
     37 
     38     def build_request(self, query):

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-e6edc2d5-a811-4e43-a0ea-d29958d03122/lib/python3.9/site-packages/office365/runtime/client_request.py in execute_request_direct(self, request)
     84         :type request: office365.runtime.http.request_options.RequestOptions
     85         """
---> 86         self.context.authenticate_request(request)
     87         if request.method == HttpMethod.Post:
     88             if request.is_bytes or request.is_file:

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-e6edc2d5-a811-4e43-a0ea-d29958d03122/lib/python3.9/site-packages/office365/sharepoint/client_context.py in authenticate_request(self, request)
    238 
    239     def authenticate_request(self, request):
--> 240         self.authentication_context.authenticate_request(request)
    241 
    242     def _build_modification_query(self, request):

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-e6edc2d5-a811-4e43-a0ea-d29958d03122/lib/python3.9/site-packages/office365/runtime/auth/authentication_context.py in authenticate_request(self, request)
     95         :type request: office365.runtime.http.request_options.RequestOptions
     96         """
---> 97         self._provider.authenticate_request(request)

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-e6edc2d5-a811-4e43-a0ea-d29958d03122/lib/python3.9/site-packages/office365/runtime/auth/providers/acs_token_provider.py in authenticate_request(self, request)
     29         :type request: office365.runtime.http.request_options.RequestOptions
     30         """
---> 31         self.ensure_app_only_access_token()
     32         request.set_header('Authorization', self._get_authorization_header())
     33 

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-e6edc2d5-a811-4e43-a0ea-d29958d03122/lib/python3.9/site-packages/office365/runtime/auth/providers/acs_token_provider.py in ensure_app_only_access_token(self)
     34     def ensure_app_only_access_token(self):
     35         if self._cached_token is None:
---> 36             self._cached_token = self.get_app_only_access_token()
     37         return self._cached_token and self._cached_token.is_valid
     38 

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-e6edc2d5-a811-4e43-a0ea-d29958d03122/lib/python3.9/site-packages/office365/runtime/auth/providers/acs_token_provider.py in get_app_only_access_token(self)
     43             return self._get_app_only_access_token(url_info.hostname, realm)
     44         except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
---> 45             self.error = e.response.text
     46             raise ValueError(e.response.text)
     47 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

### Tried solutions:

#### Attempt 1:

```py
ctx = ClientContext(sharepoint_url).with_credentials(client_credentials)

request = RequestOptions("{0}/_api/web/".format(sharepoint_url))
request.verify = False
response = ctx.execute_request_direct(request)  # <<< crashes here... example outdated?
json = json.loads(response.content)
web_title = json['d']['Title']
print("Web title: {0}".format(web_title))
```

Results in:

`TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, RequestOptions found`

#### Attempt 2:

Based on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445981/how-do-i-disable-the-security-certificate-check-in-python-requests).

```py
# If you're using a third-party module and want to disable the checks,
# here's a context manager that monkey patches `requests` and changes 
# it so that verify=False is the default and suppresses the warning.

import warnings
import contextlib

import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

old_merge_environment_settings = requests.Session.merge_environment_settings

@contextlib.contextmanager
def no_ssl_verification():
    opened_adapters = set()

    def merge_environment_settings(self, url, proxies, stream, verify, cert):
        # Verification happens only once per connection so we need to close
        # all the opened adapters once we're done. Otherwise, the effects of
        # verify=False persist beyond the end of this context manager.
        opened_adapters.add(self.get_adapter(url))

        settings = old_merge_environment_settings(self, url, proxies, stream, verify, cert)
        settings['verify'] = False

        return settings

    requests.Session.merge_environment_settings = merge_environment_settings

    try:
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter('ignore', InsecureRequestWarning)
            yield
    finally:
        requests.Session.merge_environment_settings = old_merge_environment_settings

        for adapter in opened_adapters:
            try:
                adapter.close()
            except:
                pass
```

And running that like:

```
with no_ssl_verification():
    function_to_send_file_to_sharepoint()
```

Results in the same Max number of attempts error

#### Attempt 3:

Based on [this github issue](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/issues/61).

```
def disable_ssl(request):
    request.verify = False  # Disable certification verification

ctx.get_pending_request().beforeExecute += disable_ssl
web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()
print(web.properties["Url"])
```

This code needs an update, since the thread was outdated. [The current api provides `pending_request`](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/16b5acec1ae5b392fb0a208393874933443edd79/examples/sharepoint/disable_ssl.py) and not `get_pending_request()`. With the fix applied, it results in the following:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got it working.

The network configuration of databricks was configured with a firewall that blocked both these URLs which are both needed:

- https://<tenant name>.sharepoint.com/
- https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net

Then it worked flawlessly.

I didn't figure out why the error is shown like this:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`