# Python SSL socket: Accept self-signed certificates

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I am traying to build a simple client-server application using pythons ssl socket module.
When running the example code provided [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#examples) the client side fails, returning that the certificate verification failed because of a self-signed certificate.
I provide the self-signed root CA certificate with `context.load_verify_locations("/home/vincent/work/CA/2/AllIO_Dev_CA_2.crt")`.
On the server side the certificate file also contains the servers certificate as well as the CAs self signed certificate as specified [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#certificate-chains) in the correct order (1st server certificate, 2nd CA certificate).
In an approach to fix the error outside of python I also added my self-signed root CA certificate to the os list of trusted CA certificates.

What do I have to do to allow for connections with a self-signed certificate?
As this is just for a proof of concept buying a trusted certificate is not an option at this point of time.

****server.py****

```py
import socket, ssl

def deal_with_client(connstream):
    data = connstream.recv(1024)
    # empty data means the client is finished with us
    while data:
        if not do_something(connstream, data):
            # we'll assume do_something returns False
            # when we're finished with client
            break
        data = connstream.recv(1024)
    # finished with client

context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="/home/vincent/work/CA/2/Dev_Server_2_Chain.crt",
                        keyfile="/home/vincent/work/CA/2/Dev_Server_2.pem")

bindsocket = socket.socket()
bindsocket.bind(('vm-kubuntu-23', 10023))
bindsocket.listen(5)
while True:
    newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
    connstream = context.wrap_socket(newsocket, server_side=True)
    try:
        deal_with_client(connstream)
    finally:
        connstream.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        connstream.close()
```

****client.py****

```py
import socket, ssl
import yaml

context = ssl.create_default_context()
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
context.load_verify_locations("/home/vincent/work/CA/2/Dev_CA_2.crt")
print(context.get_ca_certs())
conn = context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET),
                           server_hostname="vm-kubuntu-23")
conn.connect(("vm-kubuntu-23", 10023))
cert = conn.getpeercert()
pprint.pprint(cert)
conn.sendall("Test Message 101r\n")
```

```
python3 client.py 
[{'subject': ((('commonName', 'vm-kubuntu-23'),),), 'issuer': ((('commonName', 'vm-kubuntu-23'),),), 'version': 3, 'serialNumber': '3C337F71CFD1EA6D', 'notBefore': 'Nov  3 18:27:00 2023 GMT', 'notAfter': 'Nov  3 18:27:00 2033 GMT'}]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vincent/work/switchFrontpanel/application/networkDemo/client2.py", line 12, in <module>
    conn.connect(("vm-kubuntu-23", 10023))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1379, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1370, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1346, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate (_ssl.c:1002)
```

**Dev_CA_2.crt**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**Dev_Server_2_Chain.crt**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Remark: As these certificates are purely for testing purposes and are going to be disposed afterwards I don't mind sharing them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable the security certificate check in Python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445981/how-do-i-disable-the-security-certificate-check-in-python-requests)

Comment: The message suggest that the certificates are not properly created or not correctly in the chain.crt. Please provide the actual content of AllIO_Dev_Server_2_Chain.crt

Comment: @Daviid Negative, as I do not want to disable certificate checks but provide a file with a certificate which should be trusted.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I updated the post to contain the requested certificates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Dev_Server_2_Chain.crt ...

Both the server certificate and the CA certificate have the same subject of "vm-kubuntu-23". This will confuse the certificate validation process, leading to the error you see. Instead CA and server should have different subjects.

Comment: Thank you, this is the fix. I would have never considered this being an issue