# Ansible URI tasks failing suddenly with no changes due to SSL issues

Tags: ansible, ssl-certificate, uri

I have a series of playbooks that all stopped working suddenly. I have made no major modifications to the Ansible server other than running system updates, and all of the devices are firewalls / switches that typically use self-signed certificates.

I reviewed the URI module [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html) to find that there is already *validate_certs: no* set in all of the playbooks. I changed it to various iterations of "false", "False", and "No" to no effect.

The error I am seeing is:

```
fatal: [sampleFirewall]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"}, "changed": false, "field": {}, "msg": "Request failed: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1007)>"}
```

This seems almost like the module is not seeing that option in the play. I hate to default to "Is this a bug?" but I cant think of any other obvious cause unless a higher version of some module requires certificate signing or something.

This is on Ubuntu 22.04, using:

```
ansible [core 2.15.2]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/username/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/username/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/username/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] (/usr/bin/python3)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

Comment: According the error message `certificate has expired`, most probably the remote certificates has been expired. "_... all of the devices are firewalls / switches that typically use self-signed certificates._", how about updating them? "_... there is already `validate_certs: no` ..._", yes, someone could try to set that for testing. However, regarding "_... the module is not seeing that option in the play. I hate to default to "Is this a bug?"_", this might be caused py Python itself enforcing security certificate checks.

Comment: The certificate is firmware bound to the device, and I have checked the expiration date of the self-signed cert, and its showing *10/12/31, 10:00:14 PM UTC* 

_However, regarding "... the module is not seeing that option in the play. I hate to default to "Is this a bug?"", this might be caused py Python itself enforcing security certificate checks._ How would I disable that feature?

Comment: It depends, currently I have not enough information about your environment and so on. But, I would and maybe you also, start investigation with [How do I disable the security certificate check in Python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445981/).

Comment: These suggestions all appear to be for Python applications natively. Not a system-level setting. While I realize that Ansible uses a ton of Python behind the scenes, I am not using any direct Python myself in my playbook so I cant invoke those options in my playbook that I am aware of. 

Is there an INI or configuration file related to the language pack I can modify?

Comment: You can always [`validate_certs: false`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-validate_certs) on your `uri` task, although I'd highly recommend against it. Better look at the root cause of the issue. One possibility is that the root certificate in the trustees of your controller expired.

Answer (score -1):

The cause of the issue was a mixup with the order of plays.

The failed play was not for the URI play, but for another that reaches out to our password manager. The module detected an issue with the certificate on that device (the cert was expired) and triggered the module.

Because the name for the play was named similar I assumed it was complaining about the remote device and not the password manager. Lesson learned to be explicitly clear on what each play does.